# Repeating a task every x seconds while running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a location tracking app which stores user locations locally and sends them to the server every x seconds.

While the app is in foreground I could use NSTimer to schedule the server update task, but this is not possible when the app is running in background.

**How could I repeat a task every x seconds even when the app is running in background mode?**

Comment: No, unless you cheat iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using an `NSTimer`. You should instead be using the functions provided by `CLLocationManager`.

When using `CLLocationManager` you can set the property `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to `YES`. You then need to need to set the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your Info.plist to `YES` for the `location` value.

Now you will be able to receive background updates on the user's location.

`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` should continue to be called in the background.

A couple of words of warning with background stuff. Apple takes this very seriously when submitting an app. If they don't think that background updates are necessary they will reject. Likewise if you are doing more than very basic stuff in the background, they will reject it.

So if you want to sync the user's background location to a server, I wouldn't do this in the background. Instead, I would store the user's background location in `NSUserDefaults` or Core Data or something, and then when the app becomes active again, perform the server sync with the background locations.

[Here's a link to CLLocationManager for reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better registering for Significant location changes in the background this means when the users location changes significantly your app will have a small amount of time to process/send it.

This can be done easily using the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).